# Handling Multiple Swagger SecurityHandler definitions called when 1 is used?

Tags: node.js, express, swagger, swagger-2.0

I have configured Swagger 2.0 to have multiple optional security definitions.  When a users calls and endpoint that supports multiple definitions and uses one of them, all the configured handlers are called.
How should I handle requests to handlers without parameters and ensure that at least 1 security handler was called with a parameter?

I have 2 separate API keys definitions in swagger.yaml

```
securityDefinitions:
  apiKeyQuery:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "api_key"
    in: "query"
  apiKeyHeader:
    type: "apiKey"
    name: "API-KEY"
    in: "header"
```

I want either of them to work, so here is my endpoints security definition:

```
security:
  - apiKeyQuery: []
  - apiKeyHeader: []
```

And my app.js has handlers for both:

```
appRoot: __dirname,
swaggerSecurityHandlers: {
  apiKeyQuery: function(req, res, next) { console.log('Query Called!');},
  apiKeyHeader: function(req, res, next) {console.log('Header Called!');}
}
```

Expected:

```
Input: curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users?api_key=asdfg'
Output: Query Called!
```

Actual:

```
Input: curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' 'http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users?api_key=asdfg'
Output: Query Called!  Header Called!
```

It seems that both security handler requests are asynchronous and whichever callback fires first is used by the swagger to determine the next step.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that swagger calls both functions but since i used an 'OR' (docs: https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/authentication/#multiple ) if one accepts then it should move to the controller code.